# Why Rmarkdown does not render fig.caption for github_document?

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, figure

When I use Rmarkdown to render `github_document`, I try to include figure with caption. However, I find that `fig.cap` does not work in the `r` trunk if I specify the `output` as `github_document` in the `ymal`. This is also shown in the Rmarkdown [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf).

My code looks like below:

````
---
title: "This is the title of my document..."
author: "my name"
output: github_document
---

```{r, out.width='100%', fig.cap= "This is Caption", fig.align = "left", cache = FALSE}

knitr::include_graphics("XXX.png")
```
````

I am able to walk around this problem by adding `* this is caption*` right below the `r` trunk. But I am still don't understand why rmarkdown does not support using `fig.cap` directly in this specific output type.

I am sure I am missing something here, but any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: @RichardTelford thanks for your comment. But I believe this option is not available when you set the `output` as `github_document`.